# Formatting a number with Comma same as iphone calculator Formatting

Tags: ios, nsnumberformatter

I want to format the number separated by comma, same as the iphone calculator format , i just use the following code but it shows the Wrong  format  for example if i enter 100000 it shows 1,00,000 . the correct format is 100,000 Please help

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter1 = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter1 setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add grouping Size to 3 :

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter1 = [NSNumberFormatter new];
[formatter1 setUsesGroupingSeparator: YES];
[formatter1 setGroupingSeparator: @","];
[formatter1 setGroupingSize: 3];

NSString *numberString = [formatter1 stringFromNumber: [NSNumber numberWithInteger: 1000000]];
```

Comment: is it possible to have a grouping size that conforms to to the Indian style comma separation (eg 13,34,456.00) ?

Comment: @n00bProgramme: setCurrency style to @"en_IN". But this will give you currency style too. If you only want 1,00,000 then use `NSNumberFormatter *formatter1 = [NSNumberFormatter new];
   [formatter1 setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];`